# VBA - Late Binding Outlook.Mailitem to support different Excel versions

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, late-binding

My company is slowly transitioning employees from Microsoft Office 2013 to Microsoft Office 365.  This has resulted in compatibility issues between users and their different Office versions.  My main issue related to early bindings for Outlook 15.0 Object Library and 16.0.  I was able to resolve most of the issues with `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`.  However, I have a class module that is used to verify if an email is sent successfully (normal send validation methods are disabled due to company security).

Here is the full code from the class module:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem 'Code fails here.  Not sure how to late bind this. 

Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim blnSent As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   blnSent = itm.Sent
   If Err.Number = 0 Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Checklist").Range("EmailRequired").Value = "E-mail NOT Sent"
   Else
      ' If E-mail is sent.
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Checklist").Range("EmailRequired").Value = "E-mail Sent!"
   End If
   On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354032/polymorphism-in-vb-net-via-late-binding-disallows-with-events-workaround)

Comment: @supersymmetry Thanks for the quick response.  So late bindings on WithEvents is not allowed.  I get that but I am not clear if there is an alternative solution to bypassing early binding in References. I need to early bind 15.0 or 16.0 Outlook library based on user's Excel version.

Comment: afaik, early binding to earlier versions of the Object Library will work in later versions. The problem is user's with earlier versions while the code is bound to later versions. So if you early bind to 15.0, it should still work for people with 16.0. And not sure if this will help, but Outlook is the only Office app where GetObject does the same as CreateObject. Is it possible to acheive your goal by getting Outlook rather than creating it?

Comment: @tim, Unfortunately, that doesn't help since the form goes between users with different versions. I don't think GetObject versus CreateObject matters.  When I ran the code with the withevents disabled it worked okay but I lost my ability to systematically verify that the email was sent.